# prove that $(Y_n)_n$ is a submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

If $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a nonnegative submartingale for the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$ and F is an increasing and convexe function. We suppose that F has a differentiable function f. (F and f are nonnegative)

Let $X'_{n}=\max_{0 \leq k \leq n}{X_k};Y_n=F(X'_n)-(X'_n-X_n)f(X'_n)$

Prove that $(Y_n)_n$ is a submartingale.

They gave a hint : prove that $Y_{n+1} - Y_n \geq f(X'_n)(X_{n+1}-X_n).$

We have $Y_{n+1}-Y_n=F(X'_{n+1})-(X'_{n+1}-X_{n+1})f(X'_{n+1})-F(X'_n)+(X'_n-X_n)f(X'_n)=F(X'_{n+1})-F(X'_n)+f(X'_n)(X'_n-X'_{n+1}+X_{n+1}-X_n)$

then how can we prove

$F(X'_{n+1})-F(X'_n)+f(X'_n)(X'_n-X'_{n+1}+X_{n+1}-X_n) \geq f(X'_n)(X_{n+1}-X_n)$

Comment: You have gathered some terms you should not have. In particular, you seem to have turned the $F(X_{n+1}')$ into an $F(X_n')$.

Comment: because $(X'_{n+1}-X_{n+1})f(X'_{n+1})=(X'_{n+1}-X_{n+1})f(X'_{n})$ (discussion if $X'_n \leq X_{n+1}$ and $X'_n>X_{n+1}$ and $X'_{n+1}=max(X_{n+1},X'_n)$)

Comment: How do you gather?

Comment: I think what you have said is true if you write $\geq$, since $f(X_{n+1}') \geq f(X_n')$. I don't see why they should be equal though. In any case, with the inequality sign you just need to use the convexity of $F$ to finish the hint: you have $F(x) - F(y) \geq f'(y)(x-y)$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: By applying this to $F(x)=x^p,p>1$ we get Doob's martingale inequality in $L^p$